# Disable shrinking in Hypothesis

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

I have a test for which I would like to disable the shrinking phase.

I can do this

```
from hypothesis import given, settings, strategies as st
from hypothesis._settings import Phase

@settings(report_multiple_bugs=False, phases=list(Phase)[:-1])
@given(my_composite_generator())
def test_legacy_rack_conversion(input):
    assert_stuff_about(input)
```

but I don't like importing private things starting with an underscore from third-party libraries.

Is there a more recommended way to disable shrinking for a test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#controlling-what-runs

Note that you should `from hypothesis import Phase`, so there's no private API involved, but also that `list(Phase)[:-1]` is incorrect - it skips the off-by-default explain phase, not shrinking.  Better to explicitly list the phases you want.