# Using pytest and hypothesis, how can I make a test immediately return after discovering the first counterexample?

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

I'm developing a library, and I'm using [hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/) to test it.
I usually sketch out a (buggy) implementation of a function, implement tests, then iterate by fixing errors and running tests.
Usually these errors are very simple (e.g., a typo), and I don't need simplified test cases to figure out the issue. For example:

```py
def foo(value):
    return vslue + 1 # a silly typo

@given(st.integers())
def test_foo(x):
    assert foo(x) == x + 1
```

How can I make hypothesis stop generating test cases as soon as it has found a single counterexample?
Ideally, this would be using commandline flags to `pytest`.

Comment: the commandline flag for pytest to fail fast is `-x` ... is that what you are asking?

Comment: Not quite, that will just stop when test_foo fails, but hypothesis is actually doing a bunch of tests trying to explore what the smallest example of "x" is that will make the test fail. I just want hypothesis to stop as soon as it finds *any* example x, and not try to find the smallest.

Comment: So you want to disable shrinking, right?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68847232/disable-shrinking-in-hypothesis  Looks like there's no easy way to make that happen as a command line switch.  Pytest command line args are not yet defined at the moment where test collection happens, which is the point at which you would want to dynamically set hypothesis test phases.  You might be stuck with needing to update your code when you want to skip shrinking.  If you REALLY want it as a command line switch, you might want to rephrase your question since the solution will be complicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on my comment from earlier - did you look at this?

https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#hypothesis.settings.phases

Looks like there's some support for having different "Setting Profiles".  I bet you could have one where you eliminate the Shrinking phase.  Maybe that's the way to do.

Yeah! That's probably it :)  That gets you this command line option:

`pytest tests --hypothesis-profile <profile-name>`

So, **in summary**:

In your *conftest.py*:

```py
from hypothesis import settings, Phase
settings.register_profile("failfast", phases=[Phase.explicit, Phase.reuse, Phase.generate])
```

And then run it with:  `pytest tests --hypothesis-profile failfast`

Comment: That works - I created "conftest.py" with contents `from hypothesis import settings, Phase; settings.register_profile("failfast", phases=[Phase.generate])`, then as you said I can run `pytest tests --hypothesis-profile failfast.` If you could edit that into your answer I'll accept it!

Comment: I recommend `phases=[Phase.explicit, Phase.reuse, Phase.generate]` - you probably want to include explicit examples if there are any, and replay known failures from the database.  Those are standard ways to fail _even faster!_

Comment: Adding this information to my answer. Thanks @ZacHatfield-Dodds